# C# setting members from using statement

Tags: c#, using-statement

```
class A
{
  TypeX PropertyX;

  void SomeMethod()
  {
    using (DisposableType y = new DisposableType())
    {
      PropertyX = y.GetX();
    }
  }
}
```

What happens to PropertyX when Y is being disposed?
Would I rather do this, if I don't know what is being disposed with Y?

```
class A : IDisposable
{
  TypeX PropertyX { get; set;}
  DisposableType Y { get; set; }

  void SomeMethod()
  {
    using (Y = new DisposableType())
    {
      PropertyX = Y.GetX();
    }
  }

 void Dispose()
 {
   Y.Dispose();
 }

}
```

Comment: Nothing happens to `MainWindow` and its value will be preserved

Comment: the purpose of a `using` isn't to dispose everything *within* the brackets, but just the *used* instance, in your case the instance of `UIA2Automation`. So `MainWindow` stays untouched, however the provided `automation` will be disposed and thus the member within your window (if it has such a member).

Comment: What is the relationship between `MainWindow` and `automation`? Does `MainWindow` care about `automation` at all?

Comment: I don't know the relation between MainWindow and automation. That was just a syntactic example. Say I don't know if MainWindow will refer to something that is being disposed by the using statement.

Comment: I replaced my code. the quesiton is not about the implementation of automation.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: OP changed the question

Your MainWindow will not get disposed, but automation instance will get disposed after the execution leaves using block. Another way to write this would be:

```
    using var automation = new UIA2Automation();
    MainWindow = launcher.App.GetMainWindow(automation);
```

A more verbose way to write the same thing would be:

```
    var automation = new UIA2Automation();
    MainWindow = launcher.App.GetMainWindow(automation);
    
    // At this point MainWindow is already instantiated.
    // We no longer need automation instance so we dispose of it.
    automation.Dispose();
```

Quick Google search lead me to [FlaUI project](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI) and it looks like it is what you are using. Looking at the code samples, it looks like your approach is the correct one.

Comment: this was just a syntactic example.  I replaced my code to avoid confusion

Comment: Nothing happens to property X. Only Y is disposed. Using pattern is just a fancy way to call .Dispose() on your IDisposable's once the execution leaves the using scope. So you either use "using(var x = new SomethingDisposable)" or you handle it yourself by calling the .Dispose(). No need to do both.
I would look into following SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface

Comment: I updated my answer to show how it works without "using" statement. They are equivalents.

Comment: In know what using is doing and that my property is not being disposed by it. that's in the manual. the question what to do if I don't know wether Y will dispose something my member refers to.

Comment: I am sorry I can't help you.